# How does geolocation work on a windows PC on wired broadband connection?

Tags: windows, windows-7, geolocation

I'm trying to develop a web app which uses geolocation, and to begin with it worked fine on my Windows 7 PC at home, both in Chrome and Firefox.

It still works fine on mobile browsers, but has stopped working on both browsers on my PC, which made me wonder how it actually works on my PC - is it querying a geographical database of IP addresses that could now be blocking me due to overuse?

Is there any way to change the settings? The "Location and Other Sensors" control panel tells me there are no sensors installed, and nothing shows up in the event log for "Location Activity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firefox gathers information about nearby wireless access points and
>   your computer’s IP address. Then Firefox sends this information to the
>   default geolocation service provider, Google Location Services, to get
>   an estimate of your location. That location estimate is then shared
>   with the requesting website.

From: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/

This is also how Chrome determines location (Sending IP and nearby Wi-Fi info to Google Location Services). It seems likely that Windows 7 does about the same thing, though I couldn't find specific details other than it uses postal code if available.